# How to pass time to a shader in android using openGL es

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I'm quite new to openGL and have a very specific requirement to create rain effect in my android app. I found a tutorial of three.js to create such graphics but it is passing a time variable which create the moving graphic. But I cant figure out how to do it in openGL es.

```
precision highp float;
#define HIGHFLOAT highp
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;
varying vec2 v_TexCoord;
uniform HIGHFLOAT float u_time;
float Random11(float inputValue, float seed){
    return fract(sin(inputValue*345.456)*seed);
}

float Random21(vec2 inputValue, float seed){
    return fract(sin(dot(inputValue, vec2(123.456, 43.12)))*seed);
}

vec2 Drops(vec2 uv, float seed){
    float shiftY = Random11(0.5, seed);
    uv.y+=shiftY;
    float cellRes = 10.0;
    uv*=cellRes;

    float rowInd = floor(uv.y);
    float shiftX = Random11(rowInd, seed);
    uv.x += shiftX;
    vec2 cellIndex = floor(uv);
    vec2 cellUv = fract(uv);

    //center of each cell
    vec2 cellCenter = vec2(0.5);
    float distFromCenter = distance(cellUv, cellCenter);
    float isInside = 1.0 - step(0.1, distFromCenter);

    //randomly remove some drops
    float isDropShown = step(0.8, Random21(cellIndex, seed+1422.14));

    //intensity and fading the drops
    float dropIntensity = 1.0 - fract(u_time*0.1 + Random21(cellIndex, seed+3221.12)*2.0)*2.0;
    dropIntensity = sin(dropIntensity) * abs(dropIntensity*dropIntensity*dropIntensity*dropIntensity);
    dropIntensity = clamp(dropIntensity, 0.0, 1.0);

    return vec2(isInside)*isDropShown*dropIntensity;

}
void main(void){
    vec2 uv = v_TexCoord;
    //uv.x = fract(uv.x + 0.5f);
    float r = Random21(uv, 432424.0);

    //gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, vec2(ff, ff));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(Drops(uv, 123.3),0,1.0);
}
```

This is the code of my shader

I want to create a moving rain graphic

Comment: In your shader code `uniform uint u_Time;`, in the code of your application `glProgramUniform1ui(ProgramID, glGetUniformLocation(ProgramID, "u_Time"), TimeValue);`. That was the easy part, do you actually know what the shader code is supposed to do? Tthe answer shouldn't be to calculate/render moving rain graphic.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for your reply. Basically i did the exact same thing that you suggested and passed the system time in the TimeValue. Also this shader was just there for basic understanding. I tried new things and have now much more realistic animation. I will now try to optimise it.